# Android Studio using ADT method

Tags: android, android-studio

I have a problem related to Android Studio 0.8.1, I have use an application as base(which can successfully run) and make use of the original code for 2 other applications with changed strings and pics.

But instead i get this

```
  07-08 15:57:29.877  22470-22470/com.midlandici.cp E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.midlandici.cp, PID: 22470
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate application "com.android.storage.activity.Main": java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.android.storage.activity.Main" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.test.test-1.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.test.test-1, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
        at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplication(LoadedApk.java:516)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4554)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1600(ActivityThread.java:161)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1325)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5356)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1265)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1081)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
 Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.android.storage.activity.Main" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.test.test-1.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.test.test-1, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
        at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:67)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:497)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:457)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.newApplication(Instrumentation.java:993)
        at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplication(LoadedApk.java:511)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4554)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1600(ActivityThread.java:161)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1325)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5356)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1265)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1081)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

In Previous Version, i didn't see such thing happen

Hope that someone can help.

Comment: Problem Solve, as i didn't change the original code into library project

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because the OP shortly answered his own question which is not of great interest for other users.